# Dump of wikidata misses fields `modified` and `lastrevid`

Tags: wikidata

It seems like these fields are missing in json dump. 
But they are present in REST API response.

Is it bug or feature?

How do you deal with data updates?

Comment: Could it be that those fields are removed as dumps not being live data, they might be downloaded already outdated? Anyway, a related concern was expressed here https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T85101 while you may also have a look to the issues listed there https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T88991

Comment: Yes, this is related concern. Unfortunately, the tasks are still open.